# Wrong results from for loop in a method

Tags: java

I would like to understand, why is it when I specify the number for the method to sum up numbers it returns 21, but when i enter the value through scanner it gives me the correct value. For example number 3 should be 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 but its giving me 21, any ideas thanks.

```
public class sumInt
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i  = sumInt(3);
        int j  = sumInt(10);

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter posiutive integer: ");
        int k = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(sumInt(i));
        System.out.println(sumInt(j));
        System.out.println(sumInt(k));  
    }

    public static int sumInt(int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            sum += i;

        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually summing up to 6 for `i`, your current code could also be written as:

```
System.out.println(sumInt(sumInt(3)));
```

You'll need to print out `i` directly instead of calling `sumInt` on it again.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense why the weird numbers. Well thats what you get for trying to think at 1 in the morning. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

When you first do `int i = sumInt(3);`, `i` gets set to 6 (1 + 2 + 3). When you `System.out.println(sumInt(i))`, it does `sumInt(6)`, which is 21, because you haven't reset `i` to 3.

To see the actual results, you should change what you're outputting to:

```
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
System.out.println(sumInt(k));
```

Or change your initial definitions of `i` and `j` to:

```
int i = 3;
int j = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calling `sumInt` in two places, when you only meant to call it in one:

```
int i = sumInt(3); // sets i = sumInt(3) == 6
System.out.println(sumInt(i)); // prints sumInt(i) == sumInt(6) == 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `sumInt()` twice; once at the beginning, then again in the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying i = sumInt(3) so i == 6.

Then your print sumInt(i) == sumInt(6)  which I'm guessing is 21..

Answer (score 0):

You call sumInt twice for the same number.

```
int i  = sumInt(3); //i gets 6


System.out.println(sumInt(i)); //called with 6 =21
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following lines

```
System.out.println(sumInt(i));
System.out.println(sumInt(j));
System.out.println(sumInt(k));
```

You are already calculating i and j as the sum of the integers you want, and when you printout , you are again calculating sum of i and j

change the above three lines to the following:

```
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
System.out.println(sumInt(k));
```